# Facebook Graph API creation page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a facebook app. I want to create pages for my customers using Graph API. But in docs I can't find anything about creating pages. Could somebody answer is it possible or not, and if possible how can I achive that? I have been looking for previous questions and answers, but all of them are pretty old, maybe something changes since then.

Comment: Kindly elaborate what exactly you need to achieve and what else information you're looking...

Comment: AFAIK that is only possible via Marketing API, and only in the “Standard” access level. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/access#limits